# Does automata theory have many interesting open questions?

Tags: automata, quantum-mechanics

I’m studying Automata Theory and I love it. My question is, is there much more research to discover in automata theory, aside from quantum automata? Also, as a side question, are quantum automata the place to be for research in this field?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Automata occur in diverse branches of mathematics, so diverse that I'm loathe to speculate on what you've been learning about automata. Perhaps you could add some details to your post regarding what you already know about automata theory, for example what sources you are learning from regarding automata, what mathematics of automata you already understand, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a series of open problems in

J.-É. Pin, [Open problems about regular languages](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01614375v2/document), 35 years later, The Role of Theory in Computer Science, Essays Dedicated to Janusz Brzozowski, World Scientific (2017), 153-176.

Another famous open problem in automata theory is [Cerny's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronizing_word).

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you have the possibility of clicking on the upper triangle to give it a +1 (this is an independent action from accepting the answer, as you already did).